# Google wallet in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Does anyone know of the easiest way to add payment to your Google app engine.

Since Google is the maker of Google Wallet(checkout), one would think that would be the easiest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: there is no handy way to get the two to work together.

[Google’s tutorial](https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/docs/tutorial) provides the normal steps for your GAE application to use Google Wallet in Java and Python. Be warned if you use Python – as pyjwt is not provided by the framework at the time of writing – that you’ll have to create your own `jwt.py` by copying the contents of `jwt/__init__.py` in.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I guess I have to jump in head first - see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add Google Checkout or In-App Payments?  There isn't an automatic switch for either but if you're only selling digital goods, the In-App Payments API is super simple to implement.

Comment: I was going for In-App payment, I tried to generate a token with  jsontoken - but no luck. I have gone and used PayPal for now - Instant Payment Notification gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

*Java*

You need to modify jsontoken to make it compatible with App Engine. I removed all references to Joda time and made sure to import the correct classes for Apache Commons, and it worked fine after that.